# Is it ok to ask for song meanings?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'd like to know whether ELL is the right place to ask about song meanings and slangs in general. For example, `Sheryl Crow` starts a [song](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/Sweet-Rosalyn-lyrics-Sheryl-Crow/0FB96A7C24087A0A482568B2000B9A64) saying "*Slappin' leather*" which, until some time ago, I had no idea what it could possibly mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule of thumb on ELU has been that expressions **in** songs and poetry are fair game, but not "interpretation", and that seems to me a good policy to follow here, too.

At my age I'm not competent to speak to current slang; but probably many people here are. I'd certainly be interested in the questions and answers.

ADD:
Basically, I'd say if you're a native speaker and don't understand it, take it to ELU; if you're not a native speaker and either don't understand it or don't know whether it's "real" English you can use in ordinary writing and conversation, bring it here.

Comment: Um..no actually, expressions in song and poetry is [not fair game, at least not in the general sense](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/995/are-interpretations-of-song-lyrics-poems-or-other-creative-works-on-topic). That is, it depends on how you ask, what you're looking for.

Comment: @Mitch 'Fair game' in the sense that a question concerning the language in a song is judged on its merits - there's no a priori exclusion. I found 102 QQ on ELU about language in songs; 25 were Closed, but only 12 as Off Topic.

Comment: @StoneyB: OK, I'm down with that.